# Do I need to regenerate .pem file after changing provisioning profile?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I made a small app to test push notifications. Followed the tutorial on how to generate the necessary files for sending the notification server-side.

It worked fine, but then I needed to change the provisioning profile to add a few more devices, and and didn't receive the push notifications anymore.

Do I need to change the .pem certificate in this case?

Comment: You are talking about which provisioning profile?

Comment: No. I already updated the provisioning profile after adding the devices. I'm talking about the certificate used to communicate with the APNS server. I didn't change the Development SSL Certificate, but still it doesn't work anymore... Although the message is sent.

Comment: Which service are you using? Does APNS returns status of push sent or not? if you are using custom server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to disagree with Jaeger... it's not possible to add a device to a profile without regenerating a new provisioning profile. So, if you add a device, you must re-download the new provisioning profile and re-create the .pem file like you did before.

Comment: I ended up doing all the steps starting from making the app ID.

Answer (score 0):

No, You will need not to generate .PEM file, if you just add new devices to the provisioning profiles. Yes, That will require to regenerate if development certificate(.P12) or AppId is changed.